# PF port forwarding not working

Tags: network, firewall

I have the following rule in a file in `/etc/pf.anchors/`

```
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto {udp,tcp} from any to self port 25 -> 127.0.0.1 port 1025
```

The intention is to forward all local traffic to port 25 onto port 1025, this is so sent emails can be captured before they are sent for testing email delivery on websites locally.

I then have added `rdr-anchor "foo"` and `load anchor "foo" from "/etc/pf.anchors/foo"` into `/etc/pf.conf`.

When I run `pfctl -v -n -f /etc/pf.conf` I get the following:

```
Loading anchor foo from /etc/pf.anchors/foo
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto udp from any to 127.0.0.1 port = 25 -> 127.0.0.1 port 1025
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto udp from any to 10.0.1.3 port = 25 -> 127.0.0.1 port 1025
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 127.0.0.1 port = 25 -> 127.0.0.1 port 1025
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 10.0.1.3 port = 25 -> 127.0.0.1 port 1025
```

So it looks as if it should be working, however if I run an `nmap` scan on the port it says closed, or if I send a test email with `echo "This is the body of a text test-mail" | mail -s "Email test" test@test.com` the email is not caught, but also doesn't seem to get sent.

The most strange thing is that I have pretty much the same configuration for `pf` on my work Mac and the forwarding works fine.

Any ideas would be great as I don't even really know how to debug this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I'm special and the issue wasn't with `pf` at all. The problem was that postfix wasn't started! It'd still be interesting to know a way to test port forwarding though if anybody knows a tool for that.

Comment: You should mark your answer as the correct answer.